# How to automate registration of a scheduled task through GPO using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, group-policy, scheduled-tasks

I can manually run the following cmdlet on 10 nodes in AD to register a scheduled task:

```
Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName "MyTask" `
    -Action $inlinePowershellScript `
    -Trigger $myTaskTrigger `
    -Principal $myTaskPrincipal
```

I was looking at the ways to automate it on AD level (preferably without leveraging WinRM..)

According to [this article](https://sid-500.com/2017/08/25/configuring-group-policies-by-using-windows-powershell/) and the [list of available GroupPolicy cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy), it seems like the only way to configure GPO (using PowerShell cmdlets) is by using `Set-GPRegistryValue` and `Set-GPPrefRegistryValue` cmdlets.

It [seems like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20454183) following registry keys are available for Scheduled Task:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tasks
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tree
```

Given these details, is there a way to perform GPME's `computer configuration -> Preferences -> Control Panel Settings -> Scheduled Tasks -> New -> Scheduled Tasks` action automatically using `$inlinePowershellScript`, `$myTaskTrigger` and `$myTaskPrincipal`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating this.

Schedule tasks are just xml files. create a task manually, export it and import it to other servers using the scheduled Task cmdlets.

```
Get-Command -Name '*scheduled*' | ft -a 

CommandType Name                                         Version Source            
----------- ----                                         ------- ------            
Function    Disable-ScheduledTask                        1.0.0.0 ScheduledTasks    
Function    Enable-ScheduledTask                         1.0.0.0 ScheduledTasks    
Function    Export-ScheduledTask                         1.0.0.0 ScheduledTasks    
Function    Get-ClusteredScheduledTask                   1.0.0.0 ScheduledTasks    
Function    Get-ScheduledTask                            1.0.0.0 ScheduledTasks    
Function    Get-ScheduledTaskInfo                        1.0.0.0 ScheduledTasks 
...
```

Example:

```
# Create your task 
$A = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute 'powershell' -Argument 'Hello, from task scheduler'
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -WeeksInterval 1 -DaysOfWeek Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday -At 8am
$S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$D = New-ScheduledTask -Action $A -Trigger $T -Settings $S
$Task = Register-ScheduledTask 'TestTask' -InputObject $D

# View the created task XML
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\TestTask'  | Out-GridView
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks'

Export-ScheduledTask 'TestTask' | 
out-file '\\TargetServer\c$\public\TestTask.xml'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'TargetServer' -ScriptBlock {
    Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content 'C:\Users\public\TestTask.xml' | out-string) -TaskName 'TestTask'
}
```

Just use a list of servers in a loop the registration